# post to actionresult redirect to partial view refreshing page

Tags: ajax, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a post request to an action method that is of type `ActionResult`, however this method redirects to a `PartialViewResult` method, but my view is refreshing, and I don't want it to, any idea why this is happening, heres the pseudo-code:

```
XMLHttpRequest.open('POST', 'Controller/HandleUpload', true)

public ActionResult HandleUpload() {
 return RedirectToAction("OtherMethod");
}

public PartialViewResult OtherMethod() {
 return PartialView();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected behaviour, you can use ajax if you don't want your page to refresh.

Comment: I see.. I assumed the XMLHttpRequest was an ajax object?